# Best way of importing JSON into mongodb database with embedded data models

Tags: json, mongodb

I have the following mongodb with two data models :

```
var FirstSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    second: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Second'}
});

var SecondSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    first: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'First'}]
});
```

A JSON with thousands of objects :

```
[{"name":"First1", "second":["second1","second2,"second3"]}]
```

And I would like to import that json into my DB. What is the best way ?

I doubt the command line : `mongoimport ........` is going to work out well with my embedded models.

Thank you for you help

EDIT :

I tried

```sh
mongoimport --db <nameOfDB> --collection firstCollection -- file pathToMyFile --jsonArray
```

But I only loaded the objects "First" and not second resulting in the model "First" having the field "Second" to null, what should I do ?

Comment: This should work? Did you try mongoimport and it failed?

Comment: Actually no. When I tried, I got an error : "mongoimport command not found" although I have installed mongodb on my computer. I have looked into the problem for some time now, but since I couldn't find a solution and I couldn't find for sure if that was really the way to go, I thought I would ask first.

Comment: Ok I solved my problem of mongoimport not found, tried the import with following command line : mongoimport --db <nameOfDB> --collection first -- file pathToMyFile and I only get the first obecjts, but the field "second" of object first is null ..... !